# VS Studio / IIS Express blocks js and css - but only on local drive

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-express

I recently moved to a new dev machine; When copying back my backups I have a problem with an asp.net (Framework 4.5.1) page:
On my new Dev Machine IIS Express starts, serves the page, but all scripts / css content seems to get blocked (404 errors).
If I open the same project from my backup location, everything seems to work fine..

Anyone came across that problem? Thank you!

(Using Win10 + Visual Studio 2017 Community - Latest update)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, while writing the problem down it came to me...
simple solution - set file permissions of your user accounts (IIS Express seems to run under user account) to full access did the trick.